# Removing index.php Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the index.php and still keep some query informations. This is what I'm trying to use:

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !(index.php)    [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ vika-flyt.dk/index.php?rw=true   [L]
```

This works for one of my other sites, which is hosted on another server. On the domain where it is working, I have to use something like this:

```
/home/web/domain_acount_name/domain.dk/index.php?rw=true
```

But I don't know the "full-directory" link for this website. I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRules operate locally for the directory where you placed the `.htaccess`. And usually you don't have to include the domain at all in the target URL, except if you need to do a redirection.

Try replacing the line containing the RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ /index.php?rw=true   [L]
```

And if that doesn't work, you might need to define a *RewriteBase* to tell mod_rewrite where your webapplication is located. (For example if it's not at `domain.com` but rather at `domain.com/app` you need to set *RewriteBase* to `app/`.)

Comment: It works with just: index.php?rw=true :-) Thanks Till Helge Helwig.

Comment: And it will do so as long as the calling URL doesn't include a directory. If those should be cought as well, you need the leading `/` in the target URL.